# NTFS-3G cpu usage

Tags: applications

my ntfs-3g application takes up to 20% of my cpu usage. I don't know any way to reduce it so I have to kill it's proceess. Any idea about fixing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd consider configuring spotlight not to index or monitor your NTFS partition.

- Open 'System Preferences'
- Spotlight
- Click the 'Privacy' tab
- Click the + and select your NTFS partition

If that doesn't work you might consider defragmenting the NTFS partition, disabling transparent compression, or updating to a newer version of NTFS-3G.

For more information Tuxera has a decent [FAQ](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-faq/#highcpu) related to performance problems with NTFS-3G.

Comment: WOW !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! THAT WAS AWESOME !!! THANKS A MILLION.